# Lasso implementation Drawback

Tags: machine-learning, implementation, lasso

Recently I've been trying to implement Lasso by myself in R, not using the "***glmnet***" package, and based on an article by Tibshirani I wrote a raw code to implement coordinate descent method, and it does successfully force many coefficients to shrink to zero. But when I try to compare my result based on a famous R built-in data set(mtcars) with ***glmnet*** package, and apply different lambdas, only to find out that while other coefficients are reasonable, one coefficient that should be insignificant remain quite large. I've been trying to figure out the reason. Specifically I have some detailed questions:

1. How to deal with the intercept in the formula? When the data set is scaled, it seems that the $\beta_{0}$ can just be set to the mean value of the response variable. But even the ***glmnet*** package produces a different intercept when lambda is changed in the model.
2. What could be the possible reason for the problem as I described above?

Hope someone could lend a hand, thanks! If any more details are needed, I can provide them.

Here's my source code in Git. I've also described my problem in detailed in `README.md`.

Comment: There is no need to normalise the intercept term. There are multifarious reasons, one of them is that it is just a single coefficient, but there are many other than that.

Comment: Are you trying to implement just elastic net, i.e. regularized linear regression?

Comment: interesting question but it is difficult to answer since it could be just a bug in your code or something completely different. one thing to consider is that the algorithm is usually described for the case where the data already has mean zero and unit variance. you need to adjust the formulas accordingly if that's not true for `mtcars`

Comment: @oW_ But what's the case for glmnet? Seems it didn't adjust the final coefficient accordingly, because many of them remain pretty close to mine, and if they get adjusted, they should become very small, since the original corresponding data are quite large

Comment: @MatthewDrury Elastic net. The penalty term is a mixture of l1 norm and l2 norm. What can this suggest?

Comment: @Media Does that mean I don't need to update intercept in every step?

Comment: @DiaryofNewton I have to edit what I've said, by normalised I meant regularized. surely you need to update it each step.

Comment: @Media Could you provide me with more hints? As to how to update that?

Comment: this question is too open-ended for this type of forum.. if you can narrow down where the problem is you might get a better response. also it may help to add some code etc.?!

Comment: @DiaryofNewton simply like usual weight updates, update all the weights including the intercept term, and do not normalize the bias value, namely don't add regularisation term to your cost function for intercept term.